# find out time difference for every user in condition mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, datetime, having, having-clause

this is my fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=7c549a3de0c8002ec43381462ba6a801

let's assume I have the data like this

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID INT,
  user_id INT,
  createdAt DATE,
  status_id INT
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1, 12, '2020-01-01', 4),
  (2, 12, '2020-01-03', 7),
  (3, 12, '2020-01-06', 7),
  (4, 13, '2020-01-02', 5),
  (5, 13, '2020-01-03', 6),
  (6, 14, '2020-03-03', 8),
  (7, 13, '2020-03-04', 4),
  (8, 15, '2020-04-04', 7),
  (9, 14, '2020-03-02', 6),
  (10, 14, '2020-03-10', 5),
  (11, 13, '2020-04-10', 8);
  
select * from test
order by createdAt;
```

and this is the table after doing select (*)

```
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
| ID | user_id | createdAt  | status_id |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |      12 | 2020-01-01 |         4 |
|  4 |      13 | 2020-01-02 |         5 |
|  2 |      12 | 2020-01-03 |         7 |
|  5 |      13 | 2020-01-03 |         6 |
|  3 |      12 | 2020-01-06 |         7 |
|  9 |      14 | 2020-03-02 |         6 |
|  6 |      14 | 2020-03-03 |         8 |
|  7 |      13 | 2020-03-04 |         4 |
| 10 |      14 | 2020-03-10 |         5 |
|  8 |      15 | 2020-04-04 |         7 |
| 11 |      13 | 2020-04-10 |         8 |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
```

the id is the id of the transaction, user_Id is the id of the users who doing the transaction, createdAt are the date transaction happen, status_id is the status for the transaction (if the status_Id is 7, then the transaction are denied or not approval).

so on this case, I want to find out time difference for every approval transaction on every repeat users on time range between '2020-02-01' until '2020-04-01', repeat users are the users who doing transaction before the end of the time range, and at least doing 1 transaction again in the time range, on this case, users are doing approval transaction before '2020-04-01' and at least doing 1 more approval transaction again in between '2020-02-01' and '2020-04-01'.

from the explanation, I used this query

```
SELECT SUM(transactions) AS transactions,
       MIN(`MIN`) AS `MIN`,
       MAX(`MAX`) AS `MAX`,
       SUM(total) / SUM(transactions) AS `AVG`
FROM (
  SELECT user_id,
         COUNT(*) AS transactions, 
         MIN(diff) AS `MIN`, 
         MAX(diff) AS `MAX`, 
         SUM(diff) AS total
  FROM (
    SELECT user_id, DATEDIFF((SELECT MIN(t2.createdAt)
                              FROM test t2
                              WHERE t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                                AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
                                AND t2.status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
                              ), t1.createdAt) AS diff
    FROM test t1
    WHERE status_id in (4, 5, 6, 8)
    HAVING SUM(status_id != 7 and createdAt < '2020-04-01') > 1
               AND SUM(status_id != 7 AND createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01'
               AND '2020-04-01')
  ) DiffTable
  WHERE diff IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY user_id
) totals
```

and it says

```
In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'db_314931870.t1.user_id'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

expected results

```
+-----+-----+---------+
| MIN | MAX |   AVG   |
+-----+-----+---------+
|   1 |  61 | 21,6667 |
+-----+-----+---------+
```

explanation: min (minimum) is 1-day difference which happens for users_id 14  who doing approval transaction in '2020-03-02' and doing approval transaction again in '2020-03-03', max (maximum) is 61-time difference which happen in users_Id 13 who doing approval transaction in '2020-01-03'
and doing approval transaction again in '2020-03-04', average time difference is from sum all time difference in time range: count transaction happen in the time range

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT MIN(DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt)) min_diff, 
       MAX(DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt)) max_diff, 
       AVG(DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt)) avg_diff
FROM test t1
JOIN test t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
            AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
            AND 7 NOT IN (t1.status_id, t2.status_id)
JOIN (SELECT t3.user_id
      FROM test t3
      WHERE t3.status_id != 7
      GROUP BY t3.user_id
      HAVING SUM(t3.createdAt < '2020-04-01')
         AND SUM(t3.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01')) t4 ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM test t5
                  WHERE t1.user_id = t5.user_id
                    AND t5.status_id != 7
                    AND t1.createdAt < t5.createdAt
                    AND t5.createdAt < t2.createdAt)
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3474120f53ad93bf50d86eb882e3814a) with short explanations.

Comment: thaknyou sir, this is what i want.

Comment: in part of where not exists, you said "-- check that there is no approved transaction between selected transactions" did you mean that the transaction before the date range are not included?

Comment: @FachryDzaky selected transactions == transactions selected from `t1` and `t2` table copies. Look at prev. query in the fiddle. 3 transactions for user 13 may create 3 pairs: (first-middle), (first-last), (middle-last). But it you calculate maximal and average period between then the (first-last) pair must not be accounted - and NOT EXISTS removes it.

Comment: please see the edited fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=50add6a9c852b95643f0be8e9efc1b83, users "13" i change status_Id = 7 in before date range, but why the query said that users "13" are repeat users, and after that, users 13 count time difference in date range and after date range, and this is wrong because the time after time range are not counted

Comment: @FachryDzaky Oops, I have forgotten `> 1` in `AND SUM(createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01') > 1`... add it by yourself.

Comment: wow, i thought there will be more than 1 solutions, yes its solved, thankyou sir

Comment: sir , i think "> 1" put in "having sum(createdAt < '2020-04-01) > 1". and new problem is, the query counting all the date before time range, instead what i need is  only counting the last date before time range (if there's transaction before the time range), not counting all transaction before time range. check my fiddle   https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d30918957083c315b9d70f4581e66c89

Comment: in the fiddle, users_Id 13 i make several transaction before time range, last transaction before time range are in '2020-01-06', so what i want if the users are doing transaction before time range, in case users _id '13', it just counting '2020-01-06' until time range, not all transaction before time range (on this case, the query are also counting transaction users_id "13" in date '2020-01-01' until '2020-01-03' instead it only count time difference in date '2020-01-06' (last transaction before time range)