# how to take only last transaction to count timediff mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql, time, having-clause

this is the continue question from [find out time difference for every user in condition mysql 5.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63388042/find-out-time-difference-for-every-user-in-condition-mysql-5-7/63388378?noredirect=1#comment112089028_63388378)

this is my fiddle
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=31b3be9d1e2444eb0b32c262176aa4b4

i have this table

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  ID INT,
  user_id INT,
  createdAt DATE,
  status_id INT
);

INSERT INTO test VALUES
  (1, 13, '2020-01-01', 8),
  (2, 13, '2020-01-03', 8),
  (3, 13, '2020-01-06', 8),
  (4, 13, '2020-01-02', 7),
  (5, 13, '2020-01-03', 7),
  (6, 14, '2020-03-03', 8),
  (7, 13, '2020-03-04', 4),
  (8, 15, '2020-04-04', 7),
  (9, 14, '2020-03-02', 6),
  (10, 14, '2020-03-10', 5),
  (11, 13, '2020-04-10', 8);
  
select * from test where status_id != 7
order by createdAt;


+----+---------+------------+-----------+
| ID | user_id | createdAt  | status_id |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
|  1 |      13 | 2020-01-01 |         8 |
|  2 |      13 | 2020-01-03 |         8 |
|  3 |      13 | 2020-01-06 |         8 |
|  9 |      14 | 2020-03-02 |         6 |
|  6 |      14 | 2020-03-03 |         8 |
|  7 |      13 | 2020-03-04 |         4 |
| 10 |      14 | 2020-03-10 |         5 |
+----+---------+------------+-----------+
```

the id is the id of the transaction, user_Id is the id of the users who doing the transaction, createdAt are the date transaction happen, status_id is the status for the transaction (if the status_Id is 7, then the transaction are denied or not approval).

so on this case, I want to find out time difference for every approval transaction on every repeat users on time range between '2020-02-01' until '2020-04-01', repeat users are the users who doing transaction before the end of the time range, and at least doing 1 transaction again in the time range, on this case, users are doing approval transaction before '2020-04-01' and at least doing 1 more approval transaction again in between '2020-02-01' and '2020-04-01'.

for that problem i used this query based on answers from @Akina

```
-- Get pairs (current transaction, previous transaction) for these users

SELECT t1.user_id, 
       t1.createdAt, 
       t2.createdAt,
       DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt) diff
-- table for a transaction
FROM test t1
-- table for prev. transaction
JOIN test t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
            AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
            AND 7 NOT IN (t1.status_id, t2.status_id)
-- get data only for users from prev. query
JOIN (SELECT t3.user_id
      FROM test t3
      WHERE t3.status_id != 7
      GROUP BY t3.user_id
      HAVING SUM(t3.createdAt < '2020-04-01') > 1
         AND SUM(t3.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01')) t4 ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id
-- check that there is no approved transaction between selected transactions
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                   FROM test t5
                   WHERE t1.user_id = t5.user_id
                     AND t5.status_id != 7
                     AND t1.createdAt < t5.createdAt
                     AND t5.createdAt < t2.createdAt)

the output table was like this 
+----------+------------+------------+------+
|  user_id | createdAt  | createdAt  | diff |
+----------+------------+------------+------+
|       13 | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-03 |    2 |
|       13 | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-06 |    3 |
|       14 | 2020-03-02 | 2020-03-03 |    1 |
|       13 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-03-04 |   58 |
|       14 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 |    7 |
+----------+------------+------------+------+
```

the problem is, this query count time difference in time range ('2020-02-01' until '2020-04-01')  for each users, and count time difference also before the time range (see users_id 13, that users also counting time difference in date '2020-01-01' until '2020-01-03'). what i want is, if the users had a transaction before time range, i want counting only his users_id last transaction before time range (on this case, users_id 13 who i want to counting just only time difference in '2020-01-06' until '2020-03-04' because in 06 january 2020 is the date when the users last transaction before time range. so on that case, the expected results was like this :

```
+---------+------------+------------+------+
| user_id | createdAt  | createdAt  | diff |
+---------+------------+------------+------+
|      14 | 2020-03-02 | 2020-03-03 |    1 |
|      13 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-03-04 |   58 |
|      14 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10 |    7 |
+---------+------------+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you only have to exclude every transaction, that has ended before the start of the time frame `BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01`, because they don't interest.
As you are already excluding everything that is beyond the time frame

Still you know when you enter the data when a transaction starts and ends and so you should mark the rows that belong together with in an extra column  that would make your query much simpler in addition to your status that is not usable, because it repeat itself

> ```
> SELECT t1.user_id, 
>        t1.createdAt, 
>        t2.createdAt createcompare,
>        DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt) diff
> -- table for a transaction
> FROM test t1
> -- table for prev. transaction
> JOIN test t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
>             AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
>             AND 7 NOT IN (t1.status_id, t2.status_id)
> JOIN (SELECT t3.user_id
>       FROM test t3
>       WHERE t3.status_id != 7
>       GROUP BY t3.user_id
>       HAVING SUM(t3.createdAt < '2020-04-01') > 1
>          AND SUM(t3.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01')) t4 ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                    FROM test t5
>                    WHERE t1.user_id = t5.user_id
>                      AND t5.status_id != 7
>                      AND t1.createdAt < t5.createdAt
>                      AND t5.createdAt < t2.createdAt) 
> HAViNG createcompare > '2020-02-01'
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | createdAt  | cretecompare | diff
> ------: | :--------- | :----------- | ---:
>      14 | 2020-03-02 | 2020-03-03   |    1
>      13 | 2020-01-06 | 2020-03-04   |   58
>      14 | 2020-03-03 | 2020-03-10   |    7
>      13 | 2020-03-04 | 2020-04-10   |   37
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cb5de832dfe4e3f30852acdb999cd400)*

**UPDATE:**

That actually makes more sense now

> ```
> SELECT t1.user_id, 
>        t1.createdAt cretecompare1, 
>        t2.createdAt cretecompare2,
>        DATEDIFF(t2.createdAt, t1.createdAt) diff
> -- table for a transaction
> FROM test t1
> -- table for prev. transaction
> JOIN test t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id 
>             AND t1.createdAt < t2.createdAt
>             AND 7 NOT IN (t1.status_id, t2.status_id)
> JOIN (SELECT t3.user_id
>       FROM test t3
>       WHERE t3.status_id != 7
>       GROUP BY t3.user_id
>       HAVING SUM(t3.createdAt < '2020-04-01') > 1
>          AND SUM(t3.createdAt BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01')) t4 ON t1.user_id = t4.user_id
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
>                    FROM test t5
>                    WHERE t1.user_id = t5.user_id
>                      AND t5.status_id != 7
>                      AND t1.createdAt < t5.createdAt
>                      AND t5.createdAt < t2.createdAt) 
> HAViNG cretecompare2  BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-04-01'
> ```
>
> ```
> user_id | cretecompare1 | cretecompare2 | diff
> ------: | :------------ | :------------ | ---:
>      14 | 2020-03-02    | 2020-03-03    |    1
>      13 | 2020-01-06    | 2020-03-04    |   58
>      14 | 2020-03-03    | 2020-03-10    |    7
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1dbde0d6227268a4eee4dee539a5d930)*

Comment: im sorry i forgot to not put user_id trasaction diff between '2020-03-04' until '2020-04-10' because '2020-04-10' its out of range in '2020-02-01' until '2020-04-10', i want to add and createcompare < '2020-04-10' in last query but it's says unknwon coloumn createcompare https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=509325f281d2b6f4f95a423d797bedab

Comment: Yes that makes much more sense, i have updated the answer

Comment: thankyou very much sir, this is what i want, bountied for u, thankyouuu in advance